# How to make shortcut to go to specific workspace

Tags: shortcut-keys, display, workspaces, shortcuts, workspace-switcher

Ubuntu already has option to switch to specific workspace but only upto 4 workspaces.

[image]

Is there a way I can add shortcuts to go to specific workspace for more than 4 workspaces?

Note: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not from the desktop but you can from the commandline:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-5 "['<Primary>F5']"
```

and so on or nstall `dconf-editor` if you want a graphical method:

[image]